# Date automatically where clause - SQL

Tags: sql

I have on my DB the dates that I can filter like this:

```
select *
where    
a.y=2021 and a.m=2 and a.d=7
```

However if I run this query tomorrow I'll have to go there and change manually.

Is there a way to do this automatically as in if I run the query tomorrow I'll get d=8 and the day after d=9 and so on?

I tried to use get date but I get the following error:

> SQL Error [6]: Query failed (#20210207_153809_06316_2g4as): line 2:7: Function 'getdate' not registered

I also don't know if that is the right solution. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Isn't switching to an actually date type for your database column an option?

Comment: Why do you store a date value in three different columns. You should store it in a column with data type `date` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NOW` to get the current date, and use `YEAR` , `MONTH` , `DAY` to get parts of the date

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE a.y=YEAR(NOW()) and a.m=MONTH(NOW()) and a.d=DAY(NOW())
```

Comment: yes that does exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @MarianaRodrigues happy to help, you can upvote and accept the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have a `date` column in your data.  Then you can just use:

```
where datecol = current_date
```

Or whatever your particular database uses for the current date.

Absent that, you have to split the current date into parts.  In Standard SQL, this looks like:

```
where y = extract(year from current_date) and
      m = extract(month from current_date) and
      d = extract(day from current_date)
```

That said, date functions notoriously vary among databases, so the exact syntax depends on your database.

For instance, a common way to write this in SQL Server would be:

```
where y = year(getdate()) and
      m = month(getdate()) and
      d = day(getdate())
```